# Echo Two Keys at the Same Time

Tags: php

I know the title may be a bit confusing, so I'll just explain it here.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

  ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

  $db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=phppdo', 'root', '');

  $users = $db->query("SELECT * FROM pdophp");

  $table = $users->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Fetching</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php foreach ($table as $tabledata) { ?>
        <ul>
          <li><?php echo $tabledata['id']; ?></li>
          <li><?php echo $tabledata['email']; ?></li>
          <li><?php echo $tabledata['first_name'] . ' ' . $tabledata['last_name']; ?></li>
        </ul>
      <?php } ?>
  </body>
</html
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is to echo the first_name and last_name keys at the same time.  Is there a way to do this more efficiently than the followng?

```
echo $tabledata['first_name'] . ' ' . $tabledata['last_name'];
```

I just find that line of code to be super janky, I want to do it a better way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use the CONCAT function of sql:

```
$users = $db->query("SELECT *,CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) as all_name FROM pdophp");
```

And then on the view

```
<li><?=$tabledata['all_name']?></li>
```

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Efficiency is one possible metric, but you also need to consider readability and maintainability.

For large projects I'd be thinking of a templating engine, but otherwise you can use a here-document:

```
$ul = <<<UL001
  <ul>
      <li>{$tabledata['id']}</li>
      <li>{$tabledata['email']}</li>
      <li>{$tabledata['first_name']} {$tabledata['last_name']}</li>
    </ul>
UL0001;

print $ul;
```

Comment: Thanks, but since I'm fairly new to PHP (well, learning it over again because I learned under the outdated mysql query way), I'm just learning.

Comment: Well, I'd just grit my teeth and bear with jankiness, until you're ready to jump to Laravel. This way you'll have less to unlearn when you tackle Blade.

Comment: @ThomasHutton the fact that you're learning doesn't mean you can't learn how a templating engine works. I would suggest http://smarty.net

Comment: @Manulaiko It's not that I plan on not learning template engines, it's just a matter of I'll cross that bridge when I come to it.  Thanks for the site though!

Answer (score 0):

No. There is not. If you want a single `echo`, you could concatenate all your strings into a single variable first, but your syntax would not be prettier.

Have a look at something like the Twig template engine if you want your templates to look better (plus it has a lot of other benefits).

Either way you should look into separating your logic and presentation, for instance by using an MVC framework. Whatever you're building; at some point it will likely become an unmaintainable mess with your approach.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not building right yet, just learning.  I will be doing Laravel soon enough.

Comment: Okay. Good. You could ook at Iserni's approach, although I don't find it much less "janky" than what you're already doing.

Comment: To be completely honest, @nickdnk, neither do I :-) -- it appears that the title should have been something like *how to extract two fields together from MySQL (into PHP)*, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it using [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), so I don't need to use `concatenation`,`quotes` and several `php` blocks, i.e.:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Fetching</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<?php foreach ($table as $tabledata) {
echo <<< LOL
    <ul>
      <li>{$tabledata['id']}</li>
      <li>{$tabledata['email']}</li>
      <li>{$tabledata['first_name']} {$tabledata['last_name']}</li>
    </ul>
LOL;
}
?>
    </body>
</html>
```